# How to run debug on a project selected in Solution Explorer with a key combo?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to bind a shortcut that will run a project that is currently selected in the Solution Explorer (that is not the startup project of the current solution) in Visual Studio 2010?

I couldn't find any actions related to Solution Explorer specifically in Options > Environment > Keyboard section.

Answer (score 0):

Find this msdn doc http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa301747(v=vs.71).aspx, it already explains quite clearly. If you have any more doubt, we can discuss it further.

Update:
I've done this on my computer with Visual studio 2010.

[image]

After seeing this dialog, choose an action from the drop down lists under the `Show commands containing`, in your case, choose `Debug.Run`. Then choose `global` in the `Use new shortcut in` list, and in the `Press shortcut keys` your customized shortcut key, for example `Alt+r`, press Assign. Press OK.

After all the settings, I press `Alt + r`, my selected project compiles and runs, just the same as the menu Debug->Run.

Hope I've made myself clear for your solution.

Comment: I wasn't able to solve my problem using that article earlier, so I decided to ask what actions I must perform to achieve desired result. Unfortunately, your answer doesn't satisfy my needs. Also, your link leads to an earlier version of Visual Studio.

Comment: This doesn't run the currently selected project in Solution Explorer. It only does what the F5 key does, and that's running debug on the project that is set as startup project in the current solution.

Comment: @user1306322 what is the difference though? A little change will cover related issue. Anyway, we are just trying to help. Better to find the ultimate solution by yourself.

Comment: The difference is everything. What you propose is already by default covered by F5 key.

Comment: @user1306322 you asked "a way to bind a shortcut that will run a project that is currently selected", What I've offered is one solution for what you asked. Of course the F5 key does that too. I think you should clarify your question if what you post is not what you mean.

Comment: You won't be able to run a project that is currently selected in the Solution Explorer, that is not the startup project of the current solution by pressing F5.

Comment: @user1306322 So why not mentioned in your post that the currently selected project "is not the startup project of the current solution" ahead? cause it would avoid such tedious time-wasting talk with no help to what you really meant to ask.

Comment: Why did you think I was mentioning the Solution Explorer all the way?

Comment: @user1306322 OK. You've updated your question. Hope someone else would give an answer. Let me know if there is a solution, cause I want to know the answer too.

Comment: You can check the star near my question to keep track of new answers.

Comment: It is disappointing been down voted after trying so hard to help give an answer. It is by no means my favorite question, even though I want to know the solution.